# Which is correct word - lockdown, quarantined or isolated?

Tags: word-usage

As coronovirus has spread so much my country has gone into something called *lockdown* (I suspect if that’s the Law/Legislative term). But in newspapers I usually find things written like

> 25 people under quarantine by Police.

“Quarantine” is somewhat a medical term, I think it’s a kind of isolation which is prescribed by the Doctors.

Now, there is a third term, “isolation”. People in everyday life say

> I will live in isolation during these coronovirus pandemic.

But “isolation” is kind of a strong word, many times it is used for the people who are shunned or someone who has deliberately went away from society and started living in isolation.

If I’m not infected with Corona till now and I’m staying in my home all the time then which of those three words is the most suitable for describing yourself? For example if someone asks me (on phone or chats) how I am then should I say “I’m under lockdown” or “I’m quarantined” or “I’m in isolation” ?

Comment: You are self-isolating.  Lockdown is done to you- it is enforced and it can be for any number of reasons.  Quarantine is also forced isolation but for medical reasons.

Comment: Quarantine is when people or animals who may be infected with an illness are kept from mixing with the general population for a period of time, usually after arriving from overseas. In the UK we are calling it _self-isolation_ when people voluntarily stay at home.

Comment: Can I self-quarantine myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all correct, but they have different degrees of specificity.

- *isolation* is most general and describes any situation where someone stays apart from others. It can be by personal choice or it can be imposed by others. For example, a hermit lives in isolation.
- *lockdown* refers to an imposed situation where people are not allowed to leave a place.
  [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lockdown?s=t) defines it as:

> 1. The confining of prisoners to their cells, as following a riot or other disturbance.
> 2. a security measure taken during an emergency to prevent people from leaving or entering a building

The second definition is how the word is being used in the COVID-19 pandemic.

- *quarantine* refers to people being isolated for medical reasons, usually to prevent them from spreading a disease. Usually it just applies to a small number of people, but when whole communities are quarantined as we're now doing, it becomes a lockdown.

And just to be confusing, in medical contexts "isolation" is often used as a synonym for "quarantine". For example, hospitals have "isolation wards" for people with highly contagious conditions.